# SQL Server Columns exclude using NOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Having this table

```
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
------------------
1    X   Y     Z
2    X   Y     Z
3    X   A     B
4    X   C     D
```

Why does this work?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Col1 = 'X'
  AND NOT (Col2 = 'Y' AND Col3 = 'Z')
```

Result:  3, 4

And this doesn't:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Col1 = 'X'
  AND (Col2 <> 'Y' AND Col3 <> 'Z')
```

Result 0

Where is my error?

Thanks

Real Table Scripts

In the sample Col2 and Col3 is Fuente and TipoDeCuenta
and Y and Z is really "Cuenta" and "Contrato".

So I'm trying to get all but rows where 
**Fuente = "Cuenta" and TipoDeCuenta = "Contrato"**

```
CREATE TABLE [Cuentas].[Telefonos](
    [TelefonoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CuentaID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Tipo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MarcarComo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Numero] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Extension] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Localizable] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Telefonos_Localizable]  DEFAULT ((2)),
    [LlamadasHechas] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Telefonos_LlamadasHechas]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [LlamadasContestadas] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Telefonos_LlamadasContestadas]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Fuente] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TipoDeCuenta] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Telefonos_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Telefonos_Created]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [AutoDialerFecha] [datetime] NULL,
    [MarcarComoIsEditable] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [Comentario] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [Softphone_IP] [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [Softphone_User] [varchar](8) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [LastNumero] [varchar](20) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [InCall] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [ValidationStatus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('Valid'),
    [OtorgadoPor] [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('Contrato'),
    [MinSec] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ElapsedSeconds] [int] NULL,
    [IsIncomingCall] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [LastTelefonoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
    [FuentePos] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [RFC_Standard] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Particion] [varchar](3) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('LT3'),
    [ValidatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Observaciones] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [LastLlamada] [datetime] NULL,
    [SegundosInvertidos] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [_NumeroLength] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [_AllowSMS] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [_IsReferencia] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Operador] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [AutoGestorCampanas_LastHumano] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [AutoGestorCampanas_LastBuzon] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [AutoGestorLastLlamada] [datetime] NULL,
    [AutoGestorQueueID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Telefonos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TelefonoID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [Cuentas].[Telefonos]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Cuentas.Telefonos.CuentaID_Cuentas.Rows.CuentaID] FOREIGN KEY([CuentaID])
REFERENCES [Cuentas].[Rows] ([CuentaID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Cuentas].[Telefonos] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Cuentas.Telefonos.CuentaID_Cuentas.Rows.CuentaID]
GO
```

MSSQL Version: **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.4213.0**

Data Sample

```
TelefonoID  Fuente TipoDeCuenta
19323F53-5B90-4B29-B3A9-1F7531756F3D    Referencia2 Cuenta
E606EF4C-0D87-4251-8D03-DBD29E5C0BB4    Contrato    Cuenta
F0F07D4B-B91E-4D7E-9818-07EE977B8EB2    Contrato    Cuenta
FEB38C83-1F0C-404E-822F-4498416D158E    Contrato    Cuenta
90E1A714-F69F-41A8-B13A-CC7E4060EF51    Referencia2 Cuenta
3CC0ED09-B44D-43D0-A554-6855A750D391    Referencia1 Cuenta
8EA2C58A-84FF-405D-8971-63E2D3DD670E    Referencia2 Cuenta
47CB53E3-ADB3-4908-8310-74321F4E0E84    Referencia1 Cuenta
ABA5D8C8-5541-4EF4-8633-CD4E8873091E    Contrato    Cuenta
9B5E9FC4-2C0A-476B-9211-0ABE01DB2445    Referencia1 Cuenta
9782FFA9-C4DB-4594-AF60-48520BA72C20    Referencia1 Cuenta
B32B3F6B-E702-4CDB-8B68-7613EB9F1931    Contrato    Cuenta
3A73832B-CCD0-45F3-9866-DFC07CF43B24    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
24424F9C-DA7E-473E-8A4F-C82D16CC5374    Referencia1 Cuenta
AA70473B-015A-4E01-BF9A-44F2CDB70657    Referencia2 Cuenta
CF15FDB2-43BA-4C91-94BF-125DB4A27172    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
6026E43A-F631-4EFE-BA2E-F97C13106826    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
0519CE37-5C61-484A-912C-124439ACA6C9    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
73C841C9-64A1-4988-B635-528E7E4E79A4    Contrato    Cuenta
620899C4-BEE6-49C6-992A-BE135452D94F    Contrato    Cuenta
5CFF9974-8CFD-49A5-B50E-3B2E3FB57283    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
C0A41C97-F6D3-4983-BC61-EDE2C636BC81    Referencia1 Cuenta
011CD73D-D3A4-45EC-911D-656517300B04    Referencia1 Cuenta
5C55EE8E-3607-4374-9AD8-186049B9755D    Referencia1 Cuenta
C6C6C0DE-C6ED-416D-A6B4-5A00D3D1FA35    Referencia1 Cuenta
30BBEB29-5F5B-4235-B7BE-9942B98B9984    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
F6DB872E-A16B-4DC8-8A36-71A61C5CDBE4    Referencia2 Cuenta
14D0B634-D916-468E-A39E-759B148CBBF9    Referencia2 Cuenta
7FEC5995-D54E-4F34-8D0D-E7BFF7151E85    Referencia1 Cuenta
C2FB4A2E-92F3-495E-9104-55EECB6A809C    Referencia1 Cuenta
24D97883-751D-41E1-87CE-952CE85C0BEC    Referencia2 Cuenta
ABEDD980-126A-4E87-AD0D-D436FC260C0F    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
5DC540A3-4496-44DE-8358-ABC33D0FD608    Contrato    Cuenta
CCA5C040-5E1F-4806-A3CB-545A579AB9F4    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
0559F2D8-4305-4A0E-88CE-7A8018C7983C    Referencia2 Cuenta
C415797F-97AE-4B53-83EC-268DFA2C4F6E    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
34AAEF89-6BA6-436E-803B-C08A500653E5    Referencia2 Cuenta
D9FAFAE6-F742-4D3F-9A55-865D286C727F    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
A5D1E54C-52DC-404F-AFF8-B3CC250760A5    Referencia1 Cuenta
18C49E62-99C5-4C08-997E-5B1BB016A602    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
E3CE0653-536A-4E4E-88F1-9FBA140482C9    Contrato    Cuenta
2D123DE4-D959-482C-A1A2-E0EF93535D5A    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
193EDA9F-3384-4837-A1B5-0352D2BB30E6    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
31514FE6-F429-4844-9490-B5553E5BB912    Referencia1 Cuenta
92B0D54B-B230-4E8B-84AE-13CD6F45488C    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
7607FF87-608E-46B0-8812-351562BDA1B1    Contrato    Cuenta
126A9C1E-47A3-462C-BC6C-8E9FF31384C1    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
19168F27-1CF6-4AED-9019-86505ECBB8CA    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
4B4D69F2-856B-4E84-BC2D-A1CBA46A3E41    Contrato    Cuenta
B83AAD99-52E5-48F4-9DFF-EB48DAB66195    Contrato    Cuenta
2490C7E9-7D25-4E6B-8558-D41EB48A188B    Contrato    Cuenta
E7D2962C-DFE1-4419-B344-7B7FC21A8AA2    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
CC693422-AA38-4D50-B928-D09BD742293C    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
AE392552-BDA4-4287-9E55-223BB5E1E45E    Contrato    Cuenta
A62020FA-9009-4E55-8B24-B3D296BC1DBB    Contrato    Cuenta
B51A6A74-B458-4AC1-A2D2-0067573897D6    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
FA4DE380-2D32-45E1-A61E-041492F3EA37    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
C88FF862-90AC-413B-A724-3A3F98C7E08E    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
2205B765-B519-4A3F-B993-F52D40CBEB4F    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
27FC82F7-4CF2-412D-9EE4-E3A1DE040F6E    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
BDD11BAE-CDA8-4365-9AB0-C190F48C719A    Contrato    Cuenta
53595CD1-C629-489D-B158-704BBDED0EB2    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
69D71891-4759-4DD7-B21D-1CED2297621B    Contrato    Cuenta
CC139072-2A92-4CD1-A90C-E65F5E9E44EA    Contrato    Cuenta
E949AE78-F3E5-453E-AE07-E07E6F2CC450    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
E6984334-958B-4753-AF9C-43446F893693    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
4FF7BBBA-6491-444D-9912-9C7DCB42FEE0    Contrato    Cuenta
3146D0BC-3F71-4A49-9B66-47E5D3B0A1D4    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
ED1F03CF-CD77-48E0-AC3B-CCDB60230792    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
CFF1B65A-9420-40BC-A6A4-FAE273EBD169    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
46D6E482-9E8D-4566-BEAB-2C142A171B1B    Referencia1 Cuenta
02C75958-D573-43FF-837C-10337FF7906B    Contrato    Cuenta
E07B9867-F7AB-4579-97CB-D6344BECAE4D    Referencia1 Cuenta
DF1056ED-281F-4315-9C0B-C5AFAF03AAAA    Referencia1 Cuenta
0EE3D297-F37B-44C8-A403-3FCF35CDF827    Referencia1 Cuenta
663E9CBF-FD3E-4714-8628-2CA87090AD25    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
9C0966D4-BAD8-4413-A7AA-C59038AEB25E    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
E98126D1-805E-4E95-8A49-D3488F7FD37A    Contrato    Cuenta
3F169824-D715-4957-899A-2B65F9CC7099    Contrato    Cuenta
F13B4F8D-9D8F-4F16-B18E-8BEA3661DB80    Manual  Cuenta
64F132A5-FA82-4461-8E89-FB7BDAECE42C    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
82234188-0F9C-458A-95EA-53653597CE00    Contrato    Cuenta
5D964190-FBAE-49EE-9A28-CFD7E44C9CEF    Referencia1 Cuenta
218C8611-8ECB-4176-AAE2-38D6D289F3EE    Referencia1 Cuenta
008D3591-5CF9-4A13-9334-C83A5AE8B0B9    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
1F951E9F-22CC-4E6B-A0DE-3340DFF925CF    Referencia1 Cuenta
3667DF14-DA6E-4020-A334-F0F86C4F17BE    Referencia2 Cuenta
A464F1ED-3919-4DCE-A9A5-5132BFD3E313    Referencia2 Cuenta
C0958D88-E122-43A9-BB1D-8F2AB7204AB3    Contrato    Cuenta
81043A21-E011-4D38-A688-4981E89F5865    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
20D4B7DC-42C9-4D47-87E1-5570847CDF44    Contrato    Cuenta
C07286A1-85B9-46C9-A7E9-FB7950352C11    Referencia1 Cuenta
C665B527-DF7F-42C6-8856-EE814E6565D1    Referencia1 Cuenta
7E1E2903-2667-446D-8C4C-50DD5A30CA20    Contrato    Cuenta
F2380AC6-1875-4982-9F0C-F5EFA7F084ED    Referencia2 Cuenta
C7DDB638-8B93-4332-82A7-46A29171FC11    Referencia2 Cuenta
ADE706EE-AB72-4C08-93D5-4C99CDEAB414    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
C30E4FE4-2CF3-4E86-9BAF-581E4F877890    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
0E70DE9A-72C5-40DF-9129-A6684988F22B    Contrato    Cuenta
59FEA829-9044-4353-8EF4-01E6D5883F77    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
A79E32AB-B048-4219-BCA2-11C80ECB6CB9    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
96D1CE75-BF38-45D5-8F93-127FE7301087    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
C40B846E-F902-49F7-8474-394E1544D98B    Referencia2 Cuenta
EE09D262-2323-4C3D-AD7B-614EE612D1A7    Referencia2 Cuenta
9FA2010E-B101-4D29-A36D-5643191EDBD3    Contrato    Cuenta
79B01482-ED28-45F2-A340-9FBE33BD89FC    Referencia2 Cuenta
C7B4C01A-A6CF-47A2-B599-48DAFB1E5E75    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
4DF818E2-E578-4A77-B69A-97AE013AC99B    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
24FFF8C0-63D0-4713-BC8D-35D91D063A4E    Contrato    Cuenta
2C01D618-2457-4503-BE64-D14D1B97544A    Referencia2 Cuenta
6211C657-8F25-46CE-9830-3AC32E1B9663    Contrato    Cuenta
EAF4DEAF-2DA8-42E0-B7CB-DABF915B151D    Manual  Cuenta
C4BDBDF7-F5A3-47B7-9931-DE17D2A0C9DE    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
3294777F-B909-42EC-ABFE-EA6710212974    Referencia1 Cuenta
6C1513A1-FE0A-4190-B5BE-13087DB4B82D    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
57A920FB-1389-442C-B2FA-5340AA2891F1    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
673D35AE-45EF-48B6-BFF5-D197BCE7A78E    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
7AAA03F7-97CB-452A-9C4F-38C45E8B17BC    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
ED8551CC-66B5-403A-BB6B-CB2C5592D707    Referencia2 Cuenta
F4D522A6-3B6D-45D5-B044-69E26C088FBF    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
39FA20EF-D1D1-441B-ACAC-45DC2005D137    Referencia1 Cuenta
39BF0CBD-8293-4D5F-9ACD-E80708F396FD    Contrato    Cuenta
40BBAE30-8BDF-4E6E-BEBF-F1E263D53213    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
451BA034-5767-4794-A826-37C71763BA06    Referencia1 Cuenta
1654E32B-00D4-4C0A-9C97-88243041279F    Contrato    Cuenta
D07F7ED7-59EE-4C8F-898F-911AC3D8CCF5    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
DBBBEF1A-67ED-41F3-8248-6E6AE196ABF3    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
C68162D6-2515-4F47-9615-42EC5812E7FB    Manual  Cuenta
76665BA3-B1E9-4D41-ADC4-880B84792FA7    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
1AE277BD-8F75-4424-B9EB-31661BE93F15    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
5C55C6B2-4B53-4210-B49B-644F80C1CF38    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
2F2B77D6-3D01-4F45-BDF4-1DF3F97699B2    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
F50B3128-951F-4536-830C-58FD250525BE    Referencia2 Cuenta
49791950-2C46-4EA9-9D7E-438C3C505C49    Referencia1 Cuenta
0B012FA5-E2D9-4A19-AA02-39BB7BC0E014    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
B8464650-D123-4215-A0A1-898E18D1C595    Contrato    Cuenta
F7324F25-EC18-46F1-A8F7-18853B0AFDB6    Contrato    Cuenta
6AD038CE-F9A1-4D93-8AE6-E54F1C014E26    Referencia1 Cuenta
F0F51311-B415-4857-A57D-EEFE594B8613    Contrato    Cuenta
B77726CF-EDA3-43D1-A64B-6D49A155D6B4    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
68DB3508-7A25-4A1A-BF57-377844078A31    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
E5A085A8-A6C1-4321-A6BD-660C1BB8655C    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
BEB957D8-310B-4477-8413-1C80B5EBBB23    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
5C653369-28E8-4727-B330-D449B01E99C6    Contrato    Cuenta
87765942-EA5C-4A43-92BA-0A1C46F8333A    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
6A0C7E8D-FD9F-4151-ACAB-BBF191E58322    Contrato    Cuenta
B4ABE328-3A86-405E-BF3A-9D92EBB8042C    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
5E8E167E-01B4-42A1-89A5-F02689BE7FFE    Referencia2 Cuenta
7428BAD5-4E16-403D-A16D-FDAD6F9CB3AB    Contrato    Cuenta
628CBD1E-9B2A-4BCB-8775-1B95E45F188D    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
B8A28CB8-C2A3-4885-A0FE-735B0526F7EE    Referencia1 Cuenta
B57EF78E-4C1B-482E-80EC-3B5DFA8535D1    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
041DAE92-5C9C-43DA-AFCD-327581C8A0A6    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
9481C6C7-0787-4DE6-8937-4A9AC503E9AB    Referencia1 Cuenta
2CE73D1A-F2EA-4149-8B4D-736ADE4019AB    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
7620A43C-46FB-4BA9-ABB4-39CCEDCAA19A    Referencia1 Cuenta
625EEE80-0EE3-4B44-AC1F-83711ED7727A    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
4DA9C57F-2860-4D2A-872A-A2141C8EE4F5    Referencia1 Cuenta
41955ECE-7692-40F9-9250-77CE58302717    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
E2322C09-E490-427E-B670-7B61964E79FC    Referencia1 Cuenta
B5725BE7-2718-40B9-B03A-5B6CC0FAB95B    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
80BBA194-9A6B-4990-838E-E8FA39EE9A4C    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
0404C506-9220-41BC-997C-7C4CE845076F    Contrato    Cuenta
A84514C2-7544-4B31-936A-D0E5C7DEBA8B    Manual  Cuenta
11BFC5F1-A88A-44E2-B4F0-EA46B0093414    Referencia1 Cuenta
CE885B6D-A632-4AC3-A813-FC3C77CA23C4    Referencia2 Cuenta
0D52BBEB-CB95-4CBE-8379-19419E1DEFA3    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
9CCD23AC-1EF6-4184-9C83-EA3641627082    Contrato    Cuenta
A66B4593-F5EC-4276-9CAF-A1F53B229B15    Referencia2 Cuenta
ECECA0C2-B3AB-480A-828B-48D291D0EBC2    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
68AF0EF2-526C-4E49-900C-CF91EEF085C9    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
5732E379-578E-47FA-9CC6-CDBD7729B561    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
9B042871-28D1-4B8D-AFF7-775B4D31882A    Contrato    Cuenta
6DBCDB07-EF23-4EE9-B85D-96D0BBC56D95    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
88C73C4C-849E-4C30-9FF2-50CED54FC637    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
0A34C6D4-94AA-45F2-BACC-484540D51E64    Contrato    Cuenta
95304A33-4E3F-4909-91C9-5AFF9AD105B6    Contrato    Cuenta
0C46E1F9-8E54-4A51-BF8D-B17ACB38D1C7    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
E83EC1B6-D0C4-43EF-A8A2-698D02E3CFD4    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
7330A9E4-2B57-43C5-8FCE-13003302BA2C    Contrato    Cuenta
D434B7D9-2624-4E83-9541-7E5C48FAC509    Referencia1 Cuenta
C6C52D42-C8A7-4620-A571-2C68C7881219    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
7F47EF50-1747-4153-8849-C6E4124FFCC7    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
245F9100-2660-410A-96BD-00EB1679B5A6    Contrato    Cuenta
F84C565B-5086-4F97-B657-82E8BDB61FFD    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
1E74331B-A12E-4D16-8EA6-D8AE0D211391    LocalizacionPrimario    Cuenta
6692AC57-790C-4A89-8FBE-585EF064D1CF    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
9462C959-800B-46E4-B7CF-B134101FA244    Referencia2 Cuenta
2E187DFF-3708-4858-BB20-CE2932942BD5    Referencia2 Cuenta
A9F2D853-EC1D-4AA3-9C70-91C85AD22EFB    Referencia1 Cuenta
8C84D315-67DA-46E7-B2BA-C41B1A20AA46    Referencia2 Cuenta
7549A048-2C8F-41A1-A903-E21F846A8041    Referencia1 Cuenta
D7C7F3FC-E8F7-4620-8544-4AA6A8FE7819    Referencia1 Cuenta
4354E7FB-0CB4-41D8-9ECD-D210D5C02961    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
DB0866C0-8FFB-4D0C-8143-28B059FB58DC    Referencia2 Cuenta
0D0F9331-E703-449E-A282-092447AB1D4E    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
5D273770-DC20-46E0-8105-4488655ED983    LocalizacionSecundario  Cuenta
7B90BEBB-F464-4202-9544-CAD08EC1F6CE    Contrato    CuentaRelacionada
7F7D6EA9-B3FF-401B-A7B0-68420B708EF4    Contrato    Cuenta
9ACE03DE-7B83-4368-B1ED-A5B8FB6D53BD    Contrato    Cuenta
```

Data size:

[image]

Tries:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question.  Both of your queries work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a7d15/2

Comment: Yes, both are working I have just tested in SQLServer-2012 and I have defined first column as INT and others as CHAR(1). Can you please mention the version where you are getting issue

Answer (score 4):

You need `OR` for the two to be equivalent.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Col1 = 'X' AND 
      (Col2 <> 'Y' OR
       Col3 <> 'Z'
      );
```

That said, I'm not sure why your version returns no values.  The logic is not equivalent, but it should still return the same two rows.  I wonder if there was a transcription error when you wrote the question.

This is basic boolean algebra:

```
NOT (A AND B) <==> (NOT A OR NOT B)
```

Similarly:

```
NOT (A OR B) <==> (NOT A AND NOT B)
```

Note:  This equivalence is not exactly true when you have `NULL` values, but that does not seem to be a consideration in your question.

Comment: I extended the question

Comment: @Fraga . . . Changing the question after it has been answered is impolite.  Changes in the question can invalidate answers and draw downvotes.  You should ask another question if you have another question.

Comment: I didn't change the question, just add the real table.

Answer (score 0):

It should do,

Check out this sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/909bf/1)

Comment: In the fiddle works! but in my own server is not working! I extend the question for the more information. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be NULL values in your table and they are causing problems while comparing. 
Can you try out with the below query.

```
     SELECT *
     FROM TABLE
     WHERE Col1 = 'X' AND 
           ( ISNULL (Col2 ,'') != 'Y' 
             AND  ISNULL (Col3 ,'')!= 'Z'
            );
```

Comment: I already tried this! I thought this was going to be the answer! but not! Thanks!